# How to create a floating bar chart in highcharts.js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts.js 10.3.3 and I can't seem to add a floating bar for a series. I see they have a 'columnrange' datatype which is what I'm looking for but I need it to run horizontally instead of vertically. I can't seem to find the 'barrange' equivalent. Ideally, I'd just specify the left-most point and right-most point for each datapoint in my series:

```js
series: [
  {
    name: "My series",
    data: [[100, 150], [300, 450]]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You need to use the 'low' field to specify the left-most point:

```js
let chart;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: [{
                y: 10,
                low: 5
            },{
                y: 2,
                low: 8
            },{
                y: 4,
                low: 7.5
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.3.3/highcharts.js"></script>
```